# How to select default Woocommerce category page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change my woocommerce category page.I dont want to make php file.I want to select a page made by Elementor on wp-admin.I couldnt find the option.There are some options to select other pages such as cart or shopping but I couldnt find what I seach.

> Also I wonder why some users give negatif point my questions.Please,
>   write a comment that what should I add more to my question before do
>   it.It will help to develope my question.Without it, I will think that there some troll users who use this website to give negatif points to the real users who want to learn something.

*Thanks*